# How did Esmeralda make the Fates?

Tags: caraval

In *Finale*, the third book of the series that begins with *Caraval*, we learn that the witch Esmeralda helped the first Fate, the Fallen Star, create all the other Fates. Similarly, Legend suggests that he could turn Donatella into an immortal through a similar process. However, it is not explicitly laid out how this would work.

How did Esmeralda create the Fates? More generally, what is the means of creating an immortal in the first place?